# `direct-vuex` has error when defining Getters: "Function implicitly has return type 'any'..."

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I'm using `direct-vuex` package to define the store for Vuejs+Typescript. I have this error when trying to define Getters:

> 'userGetters' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in its own initializer.ts(7022)

I can access `store.getters.canUpdateUsers` from my component but **the getter is just executed one time** and the type of `getters`  is any. This is the exact type of `store.getters`:

```js
(property) getters: {
    [x: string]: any;
    user: {
        [x: string]: any;
    };
}
```

This is the getter part of my module:

```js
export const userGetters = defineGetters<UserState>()({
    canUpdateUsers(...args) {
        // const { state } = userGetterContext(args);
        const { state, getters, rootState, rootGetters } = mod1GetterContext(args)
        console.log(state);

        return (
            state.currentUser.role == "admin" ||
            state.currentUser.role == "presenter"
        );
    },
});
const mod1GetterContext = (args: [any, any, any, any]) => moduleGetterContext(args, userModule)
```

And this is the module itself:

```js
export const userModule = defineModule({
  state: {
    userList: [],
    currentUser: {},
  } as UserState,

  actions: userActions,
  mutations: userMutations,
  getters: userGetters,
});
```

*I already disabled `no-use-before-define` eslint rule. It seems that it's not related to this error.*

**Update:**

I reproduced the error in this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/spring-dew-e5xrq?file=/src/store/modules/user/userGetters.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the document, the return type of getters should be declared explicitly when using moduleGetterContext:

> Types in the context of actions implies that TypeScript should
> never infer the return type of an action from the context of the
> action. Indeed, this kind of typing would be recursive, since the
> context includes the return value of the action. When this happens,
> TypeScript passes the whole context to any. Tl;dr; Declare the return
> type of actions where it exists!
>
> **For the same reason, declare the return type of getters each time a getter context generated by moduleGetterContext is used!**

https://github.com/paroi-tech/direct-vuex#in-a-vuex-module

**This is the fixed code:**

```js
export const userGetters = defineGetters<UserState>()({

    // The boolean type is defined explicitly
    canUpdateUsers(...args):boolean {

        // ...
    }
```